# Example of homology group of a simplicial complex.

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I need a little help with understanding homology groups.

In particular, consider a simplicial complex with three 1-cycles and one 1-boundary (so we have two 1-holes?). Then the first homology group is the second order cyclic group, i.e. $H_1\tilde{=}\frac{\mathbb{Z}^3}{\mathbb{Z}}\tilde{=}\mathbb{Z}^2$. Is this correct?

[image]

If so, the problem is I'm getting $\frac{\mathbb{Z}^3}{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{Z}$ here.

Comment: I don't quite understand your description of the simplicial complex. Normally you have a list of simplices, and what their boundaries are. In your case, are you saying you have one $2$-simplex whose boundary is the sum of the three $1$-simplices, who in turn join up to make a triangle? (i.e. you've taken your complex to be the $2$-simplex and all its faces.) If so, then all the homology should vanish except for $H_0$, because it's contractible. In any case, you need to be more specific about your complex!

Comment: Sorry about that, I have limited knowledge in the area. What I'm trying to describe is the 3 triangles with one of them sharing 2 edges with two others. Also two triangles are hollow.

Comment: @Kosm: Ok, that's homotopically equivalent to 3 copies of a circle with a point i common

Comment: @Kosm could you draw a picture or describe more precisely? As in, triangle A has two edges in common with triangle B, and also has two edges in common with triangle C? Or triangle A has one edge in common with triangle B and also one edge in common with triangle C? Which of the triangles is hollow?

Comment: @JoshHunt Added a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed be getting $\mathbb Z^2$ here. One way to see this is that we can shrink the "filled" triangle down to a point, leaving you with two circles meeting at a single point, whose homology is $\mathbb Z^2$.

The cycles are the free abelian group generated by $[ab]+[bc]+[ca]$, $[bc]+[cd]+[db]$ and $[db]+[be]+[ed]$. The boundaries are the subgroup generated by $[bc]+[cd]+[db]$, so you get $\mathbb Z^2$ as expected.

I don't know exactly where you went wrong in this calculation because you didn't provide much of your working, but if you're more explicit I can try to answer your question more thoroughly.

Comment: I figured it now, thank you.